# Spring batch open MultipartFile , error: 'reader is in 'strict' mode'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I uploaded a batch file from the html frontend.

In my controller, i am trying to process it

```
public @ResponseBody void customerBatchUpload(@RequestParam("batchFile") MultipartFile[] batchFile) throws Exception {

    File fileToImport = new File(batchFile[0].getOriginalFilename());

    String pathToFile = fileToImport.getAbsolutePath();
    FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile)); 
    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
}
```

In the above code the line `reader.open(new ExecutionContext());` throws a error of

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file [C:\Users\user\Desktop\criticialTest5.csv]
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
```

I tried I tried `String pathToFile = "file://"+ fileToImport.getAbsolutePath();` and 
 `String pathToFile = "file:\\"+ fileToImport.getAbsolutePath();`

both failed and gave same above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc of [`String getOriginalFilename()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--):

> Return the original filename in the **client's filesystem**.

Your **server** cannot access the **client** filesystem. How could it?

You need to call either [`byte[] getBytes()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getBytes--), [`InputStream getInputStream()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getInputStream--), or [`transferTo(File dest)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo-java.io.File-), to get access to the uploaded file content.

In your case, perhaps using [`InputStreamResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html) is the best option:

```
try (InputStream in = batchFile[0].getInputStream()) {
    FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new InputStreamResource(in));
    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    // more code here
}
```

If that doesn't work, and uploaded file size is limited, you can use `getBytes()` and a [`ByteArrayResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html).

If memory is at a premium, or you need to handle huge files, write the uploaded content to a temporary file using `transferTo(file)` and a `FileSystemResource`. Remember to delete the temporary file when done.

Comment: getBytes() and a ByteArrayResource worked well. thanks so much